# Adding type synonym family to existing class with fundep

Tags: haskell, types

There is an existing class from the Reflection library

```
class Reifies s a | s -> a where ...
```

(so I can't change this class).
I feel like it should be possible to express the functional dependency as a type family synonym in a wrapper class so that I could do something similar to

```
class (Reifies s a) => ReifiesWrapper s a where
   type ReifiedType s
```

and then in instances of ReifiesWrapper set

```
type ReifiedType s = a
```

which of course I can't do because a does not appear on the LHS. This all seems like it should be possible because (due to the FunDep in Reifies), knowing s is sufficient for finding the type a.

The overall goal is to hide the "reified type" a:

```
class Reified q where
  ...

instance (Reified q) => Blah q
   type ReifiedBlah q = ReifiedType q
```

Am I hoping for too much here?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to copy `Reifies` methods in a wrapper, then you could write something like this:

```
class R s a | s -> a where
  r :: s -> a
  -- etc.

class R s a => RW s a where
  type RT s
  r' :: a ~ RT s => s -> RT s
  r' = r
  -- etc.

instance R Bool String where
  r = show
  -- etc.

instance RW Bool String where
  type RT Bool = String
  -- no need to write r' = r, etc.

-- > :t r
-- r :: R s a => s -> a
-- > :t r'
-- r' :: RW s (RT s) => s -> RT s
-- > :t r True
-- r True :: [Char]
-- > :t r' True
-- r' True :: RT Bool
-- > r True
-- "True"
-- > r' True
-- "True"
```

so that an association between `a` and `RT s` can be expressed as an [equality constraint](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families#Equality_constraints).

---

**UPDATE**: for 1-parametric wrapper with type family over 2-parametric class with fundep:

```
class R s a | s -> a where
  r :: s -> a

class R' s where
  type RT s a
  r' :: (R s a, a ~ RT s a) => s -> RT s a
  r' = r

instance R Bool String where
  r = show

instance R' Bool where
  type RT Bool a = a
```

so that:

```
> :t r
r :: R s a => s -> a
> :t r'
r' :: (R' s, R s a, RT s a ~ a) => s -> RT s a
> :t r True
r True :: [Char]
> :t r' True
r' True :: RT Bool [Char]
> r True
"True"
> r' True
"True"
```

For example:

```
import qualified Data.Reflection as Reflection ( reflect )
import Data.Reflection hiding ( reflect )

class Reified s where
  type ReifiedType s a
  reflect :: (Reifies s a, a ~ ReifiedType s a) => proxy s -> ReifiedType s a
  reflect = Reflection.reflect
```

Comment: I need the generic type synonym (i.e. type RT s = a, without concrete types) so that I can make an instance that is parameterized only by 's'. The end goal is something like

Comment: I added some clarification to the question.

Comment: @Eric see update please. But you need to put `a` in the LHS because if your wrapper is 1-parametric then it does not have `a` in the context at all.